# How to work with Windows through Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, ssh, remote

I have to work with some **remote** Windows machines in a project, I also need to check for logs and find fixes for some bugs and things like that. But honestly, I don't like to use Windows to do this kind of work, for instance in Linux : I could use a simple command like `tail -f file.log` to follow any changes in this file.
In Windows I could use `cygwin`, but I don't like it, is a very slow program in my opinion.

So I was thinking if I can from my Linux machine mount these partition from these remote Windows machine and then work from there, is that possible ? Or access this remote Windows machine from Linux or something like that.

Any hope in my case ?

Comment: So, if I understand, you just need to access logs hosted by a Windows machine, from a Linux computer ? If so, ever considered using a Shared Folder ?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking about to do, is that possible ? And how can I do that from both sides ? Did you think that is a good approach ?

Comment: Yes, you can easily setup a shared folder from Windows, and mount it on your Linux machine. more infos : http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-mount-remote-windows-partition-windows-share-under-linux.html

Comment: Note that Windows applications are prone to use some sort of binary format rather than the text-based (sometimes compressed) formats often used by *nix systems. This may or may not present a problem in practice.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no way to directly connect to a Windows system and access the Event Viewer from Linux, in the same manner you would via `mmc`.

I've had success in the past connecting to a Windows command line from a Linux system using a program called [winexe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/) - it works somewhat similar to the Sysinternals' `psexec` utility.

You can get event log information from Windows via the command line using the `wevtutil` command.  It outputs things in XML format.

So by combining the above you could check a remote Windows system's logs under Linux.

Answer (score 0):

There's remote desktop :-(

I installed Cygwin and SSHD so I could SSH in - and then run the Windows Event Viewer utility `wevtutil` to view event messages

```
ssh   -x windows.host.address 'wevtutil el | grep -i '^application''
```

Application

Comment: Nice answer! But confused by two things. What do you mean by “There's remote desktop…” and what is that word “Application” at the end of the text? Should that be part of the SSH command?

Comment: sorry for the delay in responding:

my comment about remote desktop was to use windows remote desktop - hence the sad icon.

The "^application" at the end was to grep for output lines that begin with application - though I'm not sure about the quoting at the moment